# List multiple repositories under sources.list.d?

Tags: apt, repository

Can I add multiple alternative repositories to a `*.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, so that, for a specified package, if the first repository is unavailable, `apt-get` will try to download the same package from the next repository in the list?

For example, could I create a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/games.list` with the following content?...

```
deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu trusty-getdeb games
```

...so that, if `http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` is down, will `apt-get` automatically try `http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I have answered my own question:

*The behavior of apt-get with sources.list.d is to retrieve packages from the first available repository listed in a given `*.list` file.*

The repository `archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu` was conveniently down today, so I was able to perform the following experiment to validate this:

1. I created a file called `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/games.list` with the following content:

   ```
   deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
   ```
2. Then I resynchronized the package index files from the sources:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update | grep getdeb
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
   Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
   Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en
   ```

   I noticed that apt-get warned that it was ignoring (`Ign`) the repository.
   This is because apt-get got a 404 message that the URL was not available.
3. Attempting to simulate installation of a package from this repository showed that the repository was indeed not available.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -s install warsow
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package warsow
   ```
4. Then I edited `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/games.list`, adding a mirror repository that contains the *same* packages:

   ```
   deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu trusty-getdeb apps
   deb http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/getdeb/ubuntu trusty-getdeb games
   ```
5. As before, I resynchronized the package index files from the sources:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update | grep getdeb
   Get:1 http://mirrors.dotsrc.org trusty-getdeb InRelease [8,131 B]
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb InRelease
   Get:2 http://mirrors.dotsrc.org trusty-getdeb/games amd64 Packages [69.8 kB]
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
   Hit http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
   Get:3 http://mirrors.dotsrc.org trusty-getdeb/games i386 Packages [71.5 kB]
   Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
   Ign http://archive.getdeb.net trusty-getdeb/apps Translation-en
   Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en_US
   Ign http://mirrors.dotsrc.org trusty-getdeb/games Translation-en
   ```

   Surprisingly, apt-get warned that it was ignoring both of the repositories!

   A little Internet research revealed that  apt-get displays an `Ign` warning if a repository is not available *or* if a package translation is not available. In the case of `mirrors.dotsrc.org`, the repository was up, but apt-get was requesting a translation from English to English, which obviously does not exist. So the `Ign` message for the new repository was not an error after all.
6. When I attempted to simulate installation of the same package as before, with *both* repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/games.list`, apt-get did find the package.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get -s install warsow
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   The following extra packages will be installed:
     warsow-data
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     warsow warsow-data
   0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
   Inst warsow-data (1.51-1~getdeb2 GetDeb:14.04/trusty-getdeb [all])
   Inst warsow (1.51-1~getdeb1 GetDeb:14.04/trusty-getdeb [amd64])
   Conf warsow-data (1.51-1~getdeb2 GetDeb:14.04/trusty-getdeb [all])
   Conf warsow (1.51-1~getdeb1 GetDeb:14.04/trusty-getdeb [amd64])
   ```
7. Therefore, the behavior of apt-get with sources.list.d is to retrieve packages from the first available repository listed in a given `*.list` file.